# Troca de posição em lista encadeada simples Java

Tags: java, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Tenho que criar um método que troca a posição dois elementos em uma lista encadeada simples, porém estou tendo dificuldades na criação deste método.
No caso o método recebe por parâmetro dois elementos do tipo `int`.
Ex: `trocaPosicao(int m, int n);`
Onde `m` deve ir para a posição `n` e `n` deve ir para posição `m`

Segue abaixo a classe Nó:

```
public class No {

int dado;
No proximo;

public No(int valor) {
    dado = valor;
    proximo = null;
}

public String imprimir() {
    return String.valueOf(dado);
}
```

Também tenho um classe `listaDinamica` que possui métodos de adicionar, imprimir, remover entre outros.

**Segue abaixo a classe:**

```
public class ListaDinamica {

private No inicio;
private No fim;
private int qtd;

public ListaDinamica() {
    inicio = null;
    fim = null;
    qtd = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return qtd == 0;
    //return inicio == null;
}

public int size() {
    return qtd;
}

public int sizeSemQtd() {
    No aux = inicio;
    int cont = 0;
    while (aux != null) {
        cont++;
        aux = aux.proximo;
    }
    return cont;
}

public void add(int novoElemento, int posicao) {
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao <= qtd) {
        No novoNo = new No(novoElemento);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            inicio = novoNo;
            fim = novoNo;
        } else if (posicao == 0) {
            novoNo.proximo = inicio;
            inicio = novoNo;
        } else if (posicao == qtd) {
            fim.proximo = novoNo;
            fim = novoNo;
        } else {
            No aux = inicio;
            for (int cont = 0; cont < posicao - 1; cont++) {
                aux = aux.proximo;
            }
            novoNo.proximo = aux.proximo;
            aux.proximo = novoNo;
        }
        qtd++;
    }
}

public void add(int novoElemento) {
    add(novoElemento, qtd);
}

public int remove(int posicao) {
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < qtd) {
        if (qtd == 1) {
            int removido = inicio.dado;
            inicio = null;
            fim = null;
            qtd--;
            return removido;
        } else if (posicao == 0) {
            int removido = inicio.dado;
            inicio = inicio.proximo;
            qtd--;
            return removido;
        } else {
            No aux = inicio;
            for (int cont = 0; cont < posicao - 1; cont++) {
                aux = aux.proximo;
            }
            No removido = aux.proximo;
            aux.proximo = removido.proximo;
            if (posicao == qtd - 1) {
                fim = aux;
            }
            qtd--;
            return removido.dado;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

public void set(int novoElemento, int posicao) {
    No aux = inicio;
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < qtd) {
        for (int cont = 0; cont < posicao; cont++) {
            aux = aux.proximo;
        }
        aux.dado = novoElemento;
    }
}

public int get(int posicao) {
    No aux = inicio;
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < qtd) {
        for (int cont = 0; cont < posicao; cont++) {
            aux = aux.proximo;
        }
        return aux.dado;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

public boolean exist(int elemento) {
    No aux = inicio;
    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux.dado == elemento) {
            return true;
        }
        aux = aux.proximo;
    }
    return false;
}

public String imprimir() {
    String saida = "";
    for (No aux = inicio; aux != null; aux = aux.proximo) {
        saida = saida + aux.dado + ", ";
        // saida += aux.dado + ", ";
    }
    return saida;
}

public boolean removerNo(int quantidadeNo) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNo; i++) {
            remove(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Classe que devo implementar**

```
public void trocaPosicao(int m, int n){
    add(m);
    add(n);


}
```

Comment: Querendo uma resposta pronta pro seu exercício né espertinho? =D O que você já fez? Como criou a lista encadeada de nós? Como faz para percorrer essa lista?

Comment: @mari Não mesmo é apenas dificuldade em entender essa lógica mesmo, já pesquisei um pouco sobre isso rsrsrs.Bom a lista é criada através de métodos que adiciona elementos, que no método que iniciei os elementos já estão adicionados. Para percorrer a lista utilizo um método imprimir que utiliza um for simples. A questão é somente como referenciar os nós para que eles troquem de posição.

Comment: Então coloca essa parte do código na sua pergunta para que seu exemplo fique completo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer isso:

```
public class No {

    private int dado;
    private No proximo;

    public No(int valor) {
        dado = valor;
        proximo = null;
    }

    private No posicao(int k) {
        if (k == 0) return this;
        if (k < 0 || proximo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return proximo.posicao(k - 1);
    }

    public String imprimir() {
        return String.valueOf(dado);
    }

    public void trocaPosicao(int m, int n) {
        No a = posicao(m);
        No b = posicao(n);
        int aux = a.dado;
        a.dado = b.dado;
        b.dado = aux;
    }
}
```

O truque está no método `posicao(int k)`. Esse método retorna o `No` que está `k` posições a frente. Tendo esse método, dentro do `trocaPosicao`, podemos obter os `No`s que estão `m` e `n` posições a frente e então trocar os seus conteúdos.

Comment: No caso na classe tem um método que acessa pela posição, eu poderia utiliza-lo para realizar a troca?

Comment: @D.rosario Sim, poderia. Mas ao invés de retornar -1 para sinalizar erro, lance exceções (elas servem exatamente para sinalizar erros).

Answer (score -1):

Só para fazer a troca de valores é simples, você cria uma terceira variável que vai servir de intercambio para a troca.

```
trocaPosicao(int m, int n){
  int aux = m;
  m = n;
  n = aux;
}
```

Só não entendi como vai se encaixar na sua classe No

Comment: Isso não funciona. Você vai estar apenas trocando o valor de variáveis locais que serão descartadas após o fim da execução do método sem fazer nenhuma alteração na lista ligada.